# How can I change the font size of the labels in corrplot's lengend, in R?

Tags: r, r-corrplot

I would like to change the size of the 1 to -1 labels in the scale that appears alongside a call to `corrplot`, but am unsure what parameter to pass to accomplish this.

An example call would look like

```
corrplot(data, method="pie", cex=2)
```

Some reasonable guesses on my part, which did not work, include:

```
cex=2 (errors/warnings, no effect)
cex.xlab=2 (errors/warnings, no effect)
cex.legend=2 (errors/warnings, no effect)
cex.axis=2 (sets axis labels of main plot 2x size, no effect on legend text)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following on @ulfelder's answer, the parameters for controlling the scale are given by cl.x, rather than tl.x.

cl.cex = 2 does exactly what is needed.